# Android - openCV, get part of image - weird behaviour

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to get part of image obtained from camera. I am using code below. When I return cameraFrame everyting is OK and whole image is showed. But When I use code below, only black image is showed. What am I doing wrong? Of course Image obtained from inputFrame.rgba has bigger width and height than I want to crop. I am using openCV 3.0.

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    Mat cameraFrame = inputFrame.rgba();

    Rect roi = new Rect(100, 100, 500, 500);
    Mat cropped = new Mat(cameraFrame, roi);
    return cropped;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found what I am doing wrong. JavaCameraView/CameraViewBase don't show image with another resolution that is set for camera.

Comment: I overrided `calculateCameraFrameSize` from `JavaCameraView` and then I go through supportedSizes and choose one supported and return it from this method.